# Secured webservice: server did not recognize the value of http Header SOAP Action

Tags: web-services, soap

It is possible to scan documents with some printer/scanner/copy device. Underwater there will executed some webserice which **copied this scanned documents as a pdf to the sharepoint portal**. The certificate of these webservice was expired. I have removed these old expired certificate and installed a new one.

After this the webservice is not working any more.

I have a test soap webserice tool with some credentials, proxy, webservice url parameters. When I test the "copyIntoItems" webmethod I got the following error:

**server did not recognize the value of http Header SOAP Action.**

Can someone tell me what the problem is and how I can resolve it? Is it the certificate or something else which pop this error?

[soap webservice test tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi8U6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

This may help to inspekt those headers etc.